# Syntax error when using nikto web security scanner

Tags: security, command-line, penetration-testing

I have a problem when I’m trying to scan application, which uses NTLM authentication. I found out that in this case I should use parameter –id and my credentials in form *user:password:domain*, but when I run nikto like this:

`nikto -h http://000.000.10.100/MainPage -id admin:anypassword:http:// 000.000.10.100 -F htm -output Results.html`

I get syntax error:

`+ ERROR: 'admin: anypassword:http:// 000.000.10.100' (-i option) syntax is 'user:password' or 'user:password:domain' for host authentication.`

Is this possible that the problem is due to special characters in password like exclamation mark? I've also tried using quotation marks, but without the positive result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *-id* parameter, remove the protocol and slashes.

Working syntax:
*nikto -h http://1.1.1.1/MainPage -id admin:password:1.1.1.1 -F htm -output Results.html*